# Baggage wrapping facilities at Chicago O'Hare airport

Tags: luggage, chicago, ord

We have to get home some swag and purchased items from Chicago, and the bags we brought are too small and too few.

Is there a shrink wrapping service at or around O'Hare that can convert our shopping bags into a single piece of luggage the airline will accept, or do we have to buy a travel bag or trolley case?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but shrink wrapping luggage seems to be considerably less common in the US than in other places.  But as another option, you can probably get a used suitcase for cheap at a thrift store.

Comment: Shrink wrapping is not widely available, as TSA loves to open baggage for inspection, so is really a waste of money in the US.  You can find cheap duffle bags and other such cavernous bags at the box stores (Walmart, K-Mart, Target) or outdoors stores all over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing **it would seem that there are no baggage wrapping facilities at Chicago O'Hare**. For starters, [the airport website does not mention baggage wrapping in their list of facilities](http://www.flychicago.com/OHare/EN/AtAirport/Facilities/TravelerServices/Traveler-Services.aspx). Moreover, neither TrueStar nor SecureWrap, arguably the two largest baggage-wrapping conglomerates operate in Chicago O'Hare airport. [At the time of writing, TrueStar doesn't seem to have a single wrapping machine running in the US.](http://www.truestargroup.com/where-we-operate.php) On the other hand, [SecureWrap covers (only) three airports in the US](http://www.securewrap.com/whereweoperate/en/usa):

- Houston, TX (IAH)
- Miami, FL (MIA)
- New York, NY (JFK)

[This TripAdvisor forum thread from 2012 also states that there are no such facilities at ORD](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g35805-i32-k5793401-Luggage_wrapping_at_the_O_Hare_Airport-Chicago_Illinois.html), probably due to the fact that baggage wrapping is somewhat unpopular in the US, compared to Europe or South America.

All in all you might be better off buying a large duffel bag to contain your smaller pieces of luggage.